# Validation of Array in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I apply validation on array elements so that it can raise an error that it can not be blank ??

```
    validates :my_arr , presence: true
```

It will check `[" "].present?` which will return `true`.But I need to check its element `my_arr.last`.

I have implemented following one in my model:

> ```
>  if self.dma_area.last.blank?
>    errors.add(:dma_area, "should be selected")
>  end
> ```

I have tried it with lot of other option like (`allow_blank: false` `exclusion` etc) and I found above one is working but I am in doubt whether it is in rails standards.

Is above solution is fine according to rails standards/conventions.??

Waiting for good working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use `before_validation` call back and reject all invalid values from your array. With that your normal validation should work fine.

You can try it like:

```
validates :my_arr , presence: true

before_validation :reject_invalid_values_from_my_arr
...

=====================
= Protected methods =
=====================
protected
  def reject_invalid_values_from_my_arr  
    self.my_arr = my_arr.compact.reject{|value| value.blank?}
  end
...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
validates :presence_of_last_element
...

private
... 
def presence_of_last_element
  unless my_arr.last.present?
    errors.add(:my_arr, "should not contain empty elements") 
end
```